# Django Test : SESSION_KEY failing assertIn

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-testing

I am using the Django Test client (django.test.Client) to run view tests. Upon attempting to use the Test Client on my index function that handles post requests for logins, it continually fails the test even though the authentication successfully occurs.

Heres my test:

```
def test_login(self):
   response = self.client.post('/login/', {'username':'user', 'password':'pass'})

   print response.content

   self.assertIn(SESSION_KEY, self.client.session)
```

So the reason i know the login process successfully works is because response.content yields HTML data from another view that can only be access if request.user.is_authenticated() is true. In other words, they must be logged in for response.content to yield the "logged in page". So given this, i can tell that the function obviously works for its practical purpose of logging the user in, however, i've been scouring the docs for hours trying to figure out why i can't access SESSION_KEY from the client session. All my reading suggests that the django test client is in fact stateful in nature and should store the session.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after much searching and asking around on #django, i made a working solution for Django 1.6.x

```
from django.contrib.auth import SESSION_KEY, get_user_model
from django.test import Client

def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()

def test_login_view(self):

    user_pk = get_user_model()._default_manager.get(username__exact='test_username_here').pk

    response = self.client.post('/login/', {'username':'test_username_here', 'password':'test_password_here'})

    self.assertEqual(self.client.session[SESSION_KEY], user_pk)
```

The test_login_view function will be the one evaluating the view in my app that handles user logins from the template form. First, i grab user_pk which is the real primary key of the given user in the database. I used get_user_model() instead of User.objects.get() because the former allows you to reference regardless of whether the User model is modified or not. Of course you can use the latter as well. Second, i go ahead and send the post request using the test client just like a standard user's browser would. Finally, i discovered that self.client.session[SESSION_KEY] contains the primary key of the logged in user. (If the login was successful, otherwise, it will simply yield a KeyError)